# Find a path with zero weight sum between two vertices

Tags: algorithm, graph

Given a weighted DAG with vertices u and v, each edge weight is either -1 or 1. How to determine whether there is a path from u to v with zero weight sum? I can only come up with an algorithm which is figuring out all paths from u to v and then sum up the weights to see if a path can satisfy the requirement. I've heard about A* approach for similar problems but I think this question should not be that complex. Is there a better algorithm for this problem?

Comment: You can employ DP to solve it since it's a DAG.

Comment: Yes probably DP can solve it. But no idea how the subproblems look like :/

Answer (score 3):

Consider the vertex `u` with successor nodes `n_i`, with respective edge weights `w_i`.

You have path with weight W from `u` to `v` if you have:

- path from `n_0` to `v` with weight `W - w_0`, or
- path from `n_1` to `v` with weight `W - w_1`, or
- ...
- etc

You can make a DP algorithm on the basis of the above, and memoizing subproblem solutions in the form of a set, containing `<n,w>` pairs, meaning "there's is a path from `n` to `v` with weight `w`."
You have a solution if the set contains in the end `<u,0>`.

Comment: The space complexity is at worst O(|V||E|), since among all paths there cannot be more than 2|E|+1 distinct weights (the highest a path can weigh is |E|, and the lowest is -|E|).

Comment: Reasonable solution. But how to determine the number of subproblems?

Comment: @haruhi93: There is at most one subproblem per distinct (vertex, total weight) pair.  That's not too many (see my previous comment), so you can just solve for *every* such pair.